# ECONNRESET after successful connection in npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy

I am trying to install a module using npm, however, after stablished connection to registry and some successful fetched packages (regardless node_modules and npm cache cleaning), I obtain the following error:

```
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@7.18.1
npm info using node@v16.4.2
[...]
npm http fetch GET 200 https://new-repo.myComapny.com/repository/npm-all/@testing-library%2fjest-dom 2124ms (cache updated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://new-repo.myComapny.com/repository/npm-all/@testing- library%2freact 4635ms (cache updated)
[...]
npm http fetch GET 200 https://new-repo.myComapny.com/repository/npm-all/react-refresh 90034ms (cache updated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://new-repo.myComapny.com/repository/npm-all/eslint-plugin-react-hooks 105045ms (cache updated)
npm verb stack Error: aborted
npm verb stack     at connResetException (node:internal/errors:683:14)
npm verb stack     at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:407:19)
npm verb stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:406:35)
npm verb stack     at node:net:662:12
npm verb stack     at Socket.done (node:_tls_wrap:580:7)
npm verb stack     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:514:26)
npm verb stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:406:35)
npm verb stack     at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:662:12)
npm verb cwd C:\myCompany\company\myCompany-ui
npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm verb argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--verbose"
npm verb node v16.4.2
npm verb npm  v7.18.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network aborted
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm verb exit 1
npm timing npm Completed in 269736ms
npm verb code 1
```

I am working using company proxy, so I have the following settings at my home in windows OS(C:\Users\myUserName) in a .npmrc file with following infromation (running **npm config ls** command confirms settings):

```
strict-ssl=false
registry=https://new-repo.myCompany.com/repository/npm-all/
proxy=http://genproxy.myCompany.com:8080
https-proxy=http://genproxy.myCompany.com:8080
always-auth=true
npm_config_strict_ssl=false
_auth=myBase64EncodedCredentials
```

I tested repo connectivity using curl directly:

```
curl -x 'http://genproxy.myCompany.com:8080' -H 'Authorization:Basic myBase64EncodedCredentials' 'https://new-repo.myCompany.com/repository/npm-all/'
```

Obtaining successful response. This is the information of my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myName-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "An myCompany myName UI",
  "repository": "https://github.com/myCompany/myName/myName-ui",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "d3": "^3.5.17",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "purecss": "^2.0.6",
    "qs": "^6.5.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-tooltip": "4.2.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.2.1",
    "husky": "^7.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^11.1.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "startdev": "npm run start",
    "startmock": "npm run start --prefix ../myName-tools/myName-invoice-api-mock-server",
    "prestartall": "npm install",
    "startall": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run startmock\" \"npm run startdev\"",
    "prebuild": "npm install",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "build:module": "env-cmd -f .env.module npm run build",
    "build:standalone": "env-cmd -f .env.standalone npm run build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Do I have a configuration issue? how I can complete my installation successfully?